# How to optimize the script

Tags: postgresql

I have the following SQL code:

```
select t1.*
from t1
join t3 on t3.id = t1.id
join t2 on t1.num = t2.num and coalesce(t1.date,t3.date) >= t2.date
```

but this script is not optimal at all, probably because of inequality in join.Is there a way to rewrite this, nothing comes to my mind

Comment: to optimize you need to add the the tables with indexes and a https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/using-explain.html

Answer (score 0):

1. you can add indexes to columns t1.id, t3.id, t1.num, t2.num,
   t1.date, t2.date, t3.date to perform an index scan while query
   execution.

   [Postgresql - Index optimization for Date columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27928/index-optimization-with-dates)
2. Alternatively, if exists, also add the Direct join condition between
   t2 & t3.
3. Use specific columns to be returned instead of "*".